# При нажатие на кнопку выдвигался блок div и при повторном нажатие на кнопку он за двигался

Tags: javascript, css

В JS CSS я новенький не могу при клике кнопки выдвинуть и при повторном клике задвинуть, получается только выдвинуть . Как мне правильно написать код что бы все работало .

```js
function tableMenu() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("menu");
  var pos = 60;

  if (elem) {
    elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
  }

}
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -15%;
  top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  animation-name: menu1;
  transition: left .4s linear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.butt-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("/public/image/user.png");
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc-ikonka">
  <button class="butt-menu" id="butt-menu" onclick="tableMenu()"></button>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <a href="user/register">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант с использованием для анимации `transform` вместо `left`

Пример

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const button = document.querySelector('.butt-menu');

function toggleMenu() {
  menu.classList.toggle('menu--active');
}

button.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu)
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  transition: transform .4s linear;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.menu--active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.butt-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("/public/image/user.png");
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc-ikonka">
  <button class="butt-menu"></button>
</div>
<nav class="menu">
  <a href="user/register">Регистрация</a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Максимально простой код приведу с комментариями. Вся идея заключается лишь в том, чтобы хранить в переменной состояние вашего меню. Показано оно или нет. Если показано, то скрывать, иначе показывать.

P.s. обратите внимание, что в `css` я поменял `left: -15%;` на `left: -30%;`, просто для того, чтобы тут в сниппете отображалось нормально все. Вы у себя разумеется можете вернуть как было.

Вот пример кода:

```js
let showMenu = false;

function tableMenu() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("menu");
  var pos = 60;
  
  if (showMenu) {
    // Если меню показано
    // скрываем его. Взял значение 
    // из css файла вашего.
    elem.style.left = '-30%';
  }
  else {
    // Иначе, если меню не показано
    elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
  }
  showMenu = !showMenu;
}
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: -30%;
  top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #E6E6FA;
  animation-name: menu1;
  transition: left .4s linear;
  animation-duration: 10s;
}

.butt-menu {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: url("/public/image/user.png");
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc-ikonka">
  <button class="butt-menu" id="butt-menu" onclick="tableMenu()"></button>
</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu">
  <a href="user/register">Регистрация</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое .